# Why can't Chrome send over a websocket in a tight loop but Firefox can?

Tags: javascript, websocket

This is a followup to my recent question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53659786/943814), since I've narrowed down the issue further.

I'm working on functionality to stream a large file from the browser over a websocket in 1MB chunks, but Chrome's websocket implementation doesn't seem to be able to keep up with the file reader. The code below works fine in Firefox (version 63), but slows to a crawl in Chrome (version 68) and appears to freeze the browser. Any ideas?

simple websocket server to receive the data:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws')

const wsServer = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 9001 })
```

browser code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input id='file_button' type='file'></input>
    <script>
      const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9001')

      const data = new Uint8Array(1024*1024).fill(1)

      ws.onopen = () => {
        for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
          console.log("send")
          ws.send(data)
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does this file streaming snippet work in Firefox but not Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53659786/why-does-this-file-streaming-snippet-work-in-firefox-but-not-chrome)

Comment: @blex That's the same question he says this is a followup to.

Comment: That other question has had no answers or comments, and is asking the same thing, but with more code. I don't think there is a need for both questions to co-exist...

Comment: Indeed. There is no point in posting a new question just to provide more details.  The original question should have been edited instead.  I'm voting to close this question.